# Legality of swapping identical pieces

Tags: rules

In an offhand blitz game **without** touch-move, my opponent, on his opening move as White, just to be a wise guy, picked up his b1 knight and put it down on f3, then moved his g1 knight to b1, and punched the clock. He did it all with one hand. Apart from rules against distracting or annoying ones opponent, did he make a legal move?

Comment: @ReinstateMonica We were playing clock-move, not touch-move. If he picked up the g1 knight and dropped it on g3, let go of it, then picked it up again and set in on f3, and then punched the clock, would you say he played two illegal moves?

Answer (score 6):

> In an offhand blitz game without touch-move

In other words, you are not playing by the official rules of any chess federation, either national or international. You are playing by your own rules. So, you and your opponent, as the arbiters of the rules you are playing by, are the ones to decide whether or not what was done was legal.

Comment: In my experience, real people commonly play blitz chess (i.e. 5-minute chess) with clock-move rather than touch-move rules. I would be satisfied with an answer according to the rules of any organization which organized competitions under clock-move rules .

Comment: I think i’m real. And i never ever played clock-move. Never. And all organizations that i know of have touch-move in their rules. So you really are on your own. There is no official answer for inofficial rules except „stick to the rules“.